# How to create custom SeekBar with TextView in Android?

Tags: android, android-xml, android-custom-view

[image]

[image]

How can I create movable `TextView` with a `SeekBar` or `ProgressBar` in Android?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of textview you can create a bitmap with text written on it. Something like this

```
SeekBar timerBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBarTimer);
if (timerBar != null) {
    timerBar.setMax((int) (Settings.countdownSeconds + 1));
    timerBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar timerBar, int arg1, boolean arg2) {
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.seek_thumb);
            Bitmap bmp = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
            Canvas c = new Canvas(bmp);
            String text = Integer.toString(timerBar.getProgress());
            Paint p = new Paint();
            p.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
            p.setTextSize(14);
            p.setColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
            int width = (int) p.measureText(text);
            int yPos = (int) ((c.getHeight() / 2) - ((p.descent() + p.ascent()) / 2));
            c.drawText(text, (bmp.getWidth()-width)/2, yPos, p);
            timerBar.setThumb(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bmp));
        }
    });
    timerBar.setProgress(0);
}
```